# How to print k for fviz_nbclust

Tags: r

How can i obtain the value of the optimum k for a k-means algorithm using fviz_nbclust?

For example, i want to print the optimal k for :

```
fviz_nbclust(data, kmeans, method = "gap_stat")
```

Answer (score 0):

I optimize the k using the following function:

```
k <- function(f){
  asw <- numeric(20)
  for (k in 2:20)
    asw[[k]] <- pam(f,k)$silinfo$avg.width

  k.best <- which.max(asw)
  cl <- kmeans(f,k.best)
  return(unlist(round(cl$centers,3),recursive = FALSE))
}
```